# Grails GORM binding field twice

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a simple domain object.

```
class Product {

    public static final String TRACE_SKU="236"

    Integer xRefId

    static constraints = {
        xRefId(nullable:true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        table 'product'
        version false
        id generator:'identity', column:'id'
        xRefId column:'xref_id'
        cache usage: 'nonstrict-read-write'
   }

}
```

I receive the following error on application startup as well as when running test cases.

```
Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.appdroplet.tricor.common.domain.product.Product column: xref_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

In addition when I examine the error logs I see this message.

```
[ 15.11.16 09:34:50.403] [main] [DEBUG] [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder] [GrailsDomainBinder] Mapping Grails domain class: com.appdroplet.tricor.common.domain.product.Product -> product
[ 15.11.16 09:34:50.403] [main] [DEBUG] [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory] Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'orgGrailsBeansConstraintsEvaluator'
[ 15.11.16 09:34:50.405] [main] [DEBUG] [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder] [GrailsDomainBinder] bound property [id] to column name [id] in table [product]
[ 15.11.16 09:34:50.405] [main] [DEBUG] [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder] [GrailsDomainBinder] Binding persistent property [XRefId]
[ 15.11.16 09:34:50.405] [main] [DEBUG] [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder] [GrailsDomainBinder] Binding property [XRefId] as SimpleValue
[ 15.11.16 09:34:50.407] [main] [DEBUG] [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder] [GrailsDomainBinder] bound property [XRefId] to column name [xref_id] in table [product]
[ 15.11.16 09:34:50.407] [main] [DEBUG] [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder] [GrailsDomainBinder] Binding persistent property [xRefId]
[ 15.11.16 09:34:50.407] [main] [DEBUG] [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder] [GrailsDomainBinder] Binding property [xRefId] as SimpleValue
[ 15.11.16 09:34:50.407] [main] [DEBUG] [org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.cfg.GrailsDomainBinder] [GrailsDomainBinder] bound property [xRefId] to column name [xref_id] in table [product]
```

For some reason Grails is binding the same property twice.

Project is using Grails 2.3.0

Comment: what happens if you remove `xRefId column:'xref_id'`?

Comment: It does not error on mapping however it appears to bind two properties: 'bound property [XRefId] to column name [xref_id] in table [product]' and 'bound property [xRefId] to column name [x_ref_id] in table [product]'

Comment: is it a problem to rename the field to `xrefId`?

Comment: That is really not an option as I would have to update all usages. Also I have the same field on other objects. It apparently does not like the name as the other objects start failing if I rename or remove this field.

Comment: you seem to have another field `XRefId`...

Comment: Not from what I can see, as a side note this only started occurring when we upgraded from Grails 2.1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not have a property ended by Id.

Having the following class

```
Book {
    Author author
}
```

`book.authorId` by grails convention means that you want to get the Id of the property author. Other use as you did, could produce an error.

The author in the book table is mapped as author_id by default.

You could learn more about GORM in its [documentation](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/index.html)

Comment: Thanks, is this documented somewhere?

Comment: I have added the doc url, it is more extended that the grails doc

Comment: I don't know if that is writen there, but i am trying to find it ;)

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as when I renamed the field it worked. However I still don't understand why it started failing after we upgraded from 2.1.0 to 2.3.0. It would be nice if it was documented somewhere. Sounds like another hidden "feature" of Grails.